# D8 -> D8 node migration

Tags: nodes, 8, migrations

I assumed that, since migrate is now in core, migrating nodes from a Drupal 8 site to another Drupal 8 site would be baked in. However, it seems not so.

I have already exported all the node configuration: fields, storage, etc. How can I get the actual node content from a Drupal 8 site to another Drupal 8 site?

Comment: This is an interesting question.

Comment: As of now, it's still an open issue: https://www.drupal.org/node/2607524

Comment: We started working on initial D8 sources for a project that we're currently working, plan to release that soon, as far as I know, there's nothing available yet as that core issue shows

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_drupal_d8

Answer (score 2):

As of Jan 11, 2017, there are still no Drupal 8 sources available, per Berdir, Mike Ryan, and others.

To follow along at home, see this issue: https://www.drupal.org/node/2607524